# Changing the source of an image (img) tag doesn't resize on IE

Tags: jquery, dom

I have an img element in my DOM. Based upon user action, I compute a URL for an image, and change the image element's src attribute (using jQuery). The new image has a different size than the old image. This works fine on Safari, but IE does not resize the display for the new image's size. I do have a .load handler on the src change (in which I make some changes to the img element's class)... if I knew how to access the image's actual size, I could set the img elements height and width properties. Are those values accessible somewhere somehow? If not, is there some other way to have the image displayed at its new size?

Answer (score 3):

I'm working in Chrome, not IE, but I was having the same problem and thought I would share for anyone else that stumbles upon this question. I solved this by removing the "style" attribute from the image before changing the source, i.e.:

> > myImg.removeAttribute('style').setAttribute('src', newSrc);

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but this took care of it.

```
$("#img").removeAttr("height").removeAttr("width").attr("src", newsrc);
```

Comment: I don't see how this would work. Correct me if I'm wrong, but from what I can see height and width are not DOM attributes - style is however. Removing 'style' works in Chrome, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would investigate other solutions, but you can indeed access that information directly

```
var myImage = new Image();
myImage.src = $("image selector goes here").attr('src');
myImage.onload = function() {
  alert(myImage.width + "," + myImage.height);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but alas when I *change* the image's src and load an image of a new size, the img element still reports the initial width and height values, not the newly loaded image (on IE, that is; as I said, the image is resized by Safari).

Comment: Try loading the image by url directly as opposed to the `attr('src')` method then. So something like `myImage.src = "http://example.com/awesome.gif"` then check the width. I can't see how that would possibly report the same width, since it should be unaware of it. This is kind of pain since it sends two requests to your server for the image, but shouldn't be an issue if there's caching.

Comment: My suspicion is that the rendering engine does layout with the first image. The subsequent image loads do not force relayout. I have rewritten my entire approach to avoid this issue.

Comment: Post your solution in case others are having the same problem, then accept the answer.